# Django Template - For loop with range

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, code-snippets

I am using the get_range filter using the custom snippet:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/#c5787

The only problem is that, this works just fine:

```
 {% for x in 3|get_range %}
                <tr>
                    <td{{ x }}></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

But this doesnt:

```
                    {% for x in 3|get_range %}
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

What I need is to create empty rows...but it's not letting me...

Thanks,
Ara

EDIT:

HEre is a screenshot when I put {{ x }}:
http://gyazo.com/83c452c2e1c77025030817951a6abf22

And here is one when I don't:
http://gyazo.com/76d98cea7089af8c23c4a0ee506c2a8c

What I would like is to have empty rows without numbers....

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Those appear to be the same. What's supposed to be the difference?

Comment: @DanielRoseman , Oups I just edited. The second code doesnt have {{ x }}.

Comment: And what do you get when you try this?

Comment: It doesn't create any rows... I will add screenshots to the main post.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , I just added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're not getting the rows? Have you looked at the HTML source not just the rendering on screen?

What you are creating in the second example is a table row with completely empty cells. In a normal browser these will have no height and so you won't see them on screen but they will be in the HTML source.

Try putting a non-breaking space in at least one of the cells ( ) then each row will have a height of one line and will display.